# JWT token authentication to websocket in GosWebSocketBundle

Tags: symfony, websocket, wamp

I created an jwt token based application with React and Symfony. Client & Server are completely separated. Symfony - API Server. React - Client.

Now i want to use websockets so i installed goswebsocketbundle. Everything works fine but unsecure. I don't know how to send token in socket/connect function or subscribe to access topic. Is passing parameters allowed in WAMP?

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the token in request header and receive it from response body. 
For dummy request tests you can use postman.

Comment: ok, but how? look at the code
window.ab.connect(
   this._uri,

   //Function on connect
   function(session) {
    that.fire({ type: 'socket/connect', data: session });
   },

   //Function on disconnect / error
   function(code, reason) {
    that._session = false;

    that.fire({ type: 'socket/disconnect', data: { code: code, reason: reason } });
   }
  );

Comment: i use autobahn, but connect function parameters are uri, onconnect, onfail

Comment: there is no parameter to set header